# Regular measure in finite Borel sets

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, borel-sets

I have a question concerning
these lecture notes, https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf

In the proof of the proposition 2.3 (page 3), there are two steps:

1) define the family $\mathcal{R}$ and prove that it is a $\sigma$-álgebra;

2) prove that this family contains all open sets.

Why do this? It is not clear to me what the relation is between the proposition and these steps in the proof.

I attempted to prove that any finite measure is regular. However, I did not see a clear reason for introducing the family $\mathcal{R}$.

Thanks for your help.